# docker : 403 Forbidden [IP: 143.204.15.85 443]

Tags: apt, 18.04

Every time I try to update my 18.04

```
Err:13 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease                                                                                            
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.204.15.85 443]
```

My curl and dig output

```
curl -I https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 110
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 09:21:30 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 23:00:23 GMT
x-amz-version-id: HeHCl3LN6plpzhibKU1V5uZfpGiawVdA
ETag: "b619bbda54539f24a971070244d36e37"
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 39195
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 ea2e21f6a5c3ec2f96b0dac1b769e00e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: FRA50-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: I8WALw5UgBf5i8FvDNgScFHeK9cpljOVQMr8-404Xl1_WJrWIQCOxg==

dig get.docker.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> get.docker.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40498
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;get.docker.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
get.docker.com.     299 IN  CNAME   d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net.
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 58 IN    A   143.204.101.25
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 58 IN    A   143.204.101.126
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 58 IN    A   143.204.101.29
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 58 IN    A   143.204.101.37

;; Query time: 78 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 18 20:43:49 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 150
```

Why do I have this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crappy DNS resolution would be my guess. `get.docker.com` uses Amazon Cloudfront.

```
$ curl -I https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 110
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:24:03 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 23:00:23 GMT
x-amz-version-id: HeHCl3LN6plpzhibKU1V5uZfpGiawVdA
ETag: "b619bbda54539f24a971070244d36e37"
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 0ea2ca4542be08b5610e21d1ffd6aa5b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: MAN50-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 6BPw0Cj6kObi8MPSpTteMhm3pxrlhSPCl3OkABfCuC7SsjR7mCL0iw==


$ ping get.docker.com
PING d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net (52.85.140.74) 56(84) bytes of data
...

$ dig get.docker.com
...
get.docker.com.     300 IN  CNAME   d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net.
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   52.85.140.2
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   52.85.140.94
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   52.85.140.74
d3cxuo8f8w64ms.cloudfront.net. 59 IN    A   52.85.140.25
```

We're seeing different IPs but that's the nature of global CDNs. They return different IPs based on where you are, and also depending on what servers they're tasking for that job. The DNS can change *all the time*, frequently.

The most likely cause of something like this is a DNS cache at your end holding onto an old resolution, pointing at an Amazon server which now no longer holds data for `get.docker.com`. As I say, these things the migrate around so any caching over the set TTL is risky.

Comment: Thanks,how to fix this?

Comment: Find where the problem is. Dig (per the commands above) is likely your best first step.